# The command heroku ssl says my domains have no certificate installed

Tags: ssl, heroku

I just want to say that this is not normally something I do, but I have been tasked with it recently... 
I have followed the [heroku documentation for setting up SSL](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#customdomain-ssl) closely, but I am still  encountering a problem.

I have added my cert to  heroku using the following command:

```
heroku certs:add path_to_crt path_to_key
```

This part seems to work. I receive a message saying:

```
Adding SSL Endpoint to my_app ... done
```

I have also setup a CNAME for my hosting service to point to the endpoint associated with the cert command above. However, when I browse to the site I still receive a SSL error. It says my certificate isn't trusted and points to the *.heroku.com license, not the one I have just uploaded.

I have noticed that when I execute the following command:

```
heroku ssl
```

I receive the following:

```
my_domain_name has no certificate
```

My assumption is that there should be a certificate associated with this domain at this point.

Any ideas?

Edit: It appears that I did not wait long enough for the certificate stuff to trickle through the internets... however, my question regarding the "heroku ssl" command still puzzles me.

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku `ssl` command is for legacy certificates:

```
$ heroku ssl -h
Usage: heroku ssl

 list legacy certificates for an app
```

The command you need is `heroku certs` which will output the relevant certificate info for that project.